# string replace using a list with a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am new to python and I want to replace characters in a string with with characters from a list for example.

```
tagFinder = ['<', '>','&']
safeTag = ['&lt;','&gt','&amp']

for i in content:
    return content.replace(tagFinder[i],safeTag[i]
```

I keep getting the following error

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

could someone please help a brother out thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You probably intended

```
for i in range(len(tagFinder)):
    content = content.replace(tagFinder[i],safeTag[i])
..........
return content
```

instead of

```
for i in content:
    return content.replace(tagFinder[i],safeTag[i])
```

and also you are prematurely exiting the loop because of the return statement. The return statement should be the last statement in your function, assuming these statements are in a function

but then it is always better to use the built-in `zip` here

```
for src, dest in zip(tagFinder , safeTag ):
    content = content.replace(src, dest)
..........
return content
```

but then, unless this is part of a homework, you should use the standard library to escape your html string. In this particular case, [cgi](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape) will be useful.

```
>>> import cgi
>>> cgi.escape(data).encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
'&lt;&gt;&amp;'
```

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable - i get that as an error?

Comment: @NubmcNub: My bad. I have corrected the typographical error

Comment: thanks im almost there but when i return it i get this 
Expected :'&lt;p&gt;Hello World&lt;/p&gt;'
Actual   :'&amplt;p&ampgtHello World&amplt;/p&ampgt'

Comment: do i hae to escape the '&'?

Comment: Change the order of your tags such that `tagFinder = ['&', '<', '>']` and `safeTag = ['&amp', '&lt;','&gt']`

Comment: okay thank you so much mate is there any reason why '&' sign must be first ?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist in doing it manually:

```
tagFinder = ['<', '>','&']
safeTag = ['&lt;','&gt','&amp']

for tag, safe in zip(tagFinder, safeTag):
    content = content.replace(tag, safe)
```

But there is a better way to escape HTML characters in Python:

```
import cgi
content = cgi.escape(content)
```